# Angular patchValue() checkboxes

Tags: angular

I am building a form that has three checkboxes:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="role">{{ 'USERS.ROLE' | translate }}:</label>
    <ul class="nav mb-3">
        <li class="nav-item mr-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" (change)="roles($event, 1)">
                        {{ 'CODE_TABLE.USER_ROLE.1' | translate }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" (change)="roles($event, 2)">
                        {{ 'CODE_TABLE.USER_ROLE.2' | translate }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" (change)="roles($event, 3)">
                        {{ 'CODE_TABLE.USER_ROLE.3' | translate }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then in my component i need to build add to an array when the checkbox is clicked, but this patchValue() seems to only modify the value. I tried to push to this.userForm.value.rolesToAdd but it was returning as undefined.

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
    accountsToAdd: [],
    accountsToDelete: [],
    email: '',
    name: '',
    rolesToAdd: [],
    rolesToDelete: [],
    userId: null,
});

roles(event, val) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        this.userForm.patchValue({
            rolesToAdd: val
        });
    }
    console.log(this.userForm.value);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: my roles() function needs to be able to add multiple roles to rolesToAdd, it seams the way I am using patchvalue() it is only adding on value based off which ever checkbox is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a FormArray for multiple values

```
import { ..., FormArray } from '@angular/forms';


this.userForm = this.fb.group({
    accountsToAdd: [],
    accountsToDelete: [],
    email: '',
    name: '',
    rolesToAdd: new FormArray([]),
    rolesToDelete: [],
    userId: null,
});
```

and patch value like this

```
(<FormArray>this.userForm.get('rolesToAdd')).push(
new FormGroup( {
   'role': val
})
```

Comment: it's telling me Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.